Обработка сообщений, которые содержат альбомы (media_group), через telegram api
Одна из задач бота (которого я пишу) - проанализировать сообщение, полученное от пользователя, и в зависимости от контента в нём, встроить клавиатуру с возможными действиями.
В ситуации, когда одно сообщение содержит только текст и/или одно изображение, всё хорошо. Получаем один update, в нём лежат все данные, извлекаем и обрабатываем.
Сложности возникают с обработкой сообщений, которые содержат так называемый альбом (медиа группу). Как пример - сообщение, в котором вложены две и более фотографии.
В этом случае бот получает такие сообщения как бы фрагментами (отдельными update'ами). Например, сообщение, состоящее из двух фотографии, бот получит по API в трёх разных update’ах.
Сложность с тем, чтобы понять:

Когда «долетит» последний "фрагмент", после которого можно приступить к анализу всего сообщения?
Как потом обратиться ко всем фрагментам этого сообщения?

Просматривая такие сообщения с помощью бота Json Dump, я увидел, что у такой «пачки» одинаковое значения поля «media_group_id». Вероятно, это и есть связующий ключ. Но два вышеуказанных вопроса по прежнему актуальны.
Не хотелось бы делать костыли в виде глобальной/статической переменной, в которой я должен запоминать начало получения такого сообщения. К тому же, у меня нет понимания: гарантирует ли API телеграмма, что между "фрагментами" одного сообщения не залетит update от другого события/сообщения.‍♂️
В общем, буду признателен за любые мысли. Желательно, на языке golang. Но можно и на другом. Мне важно понять подход, как подступиться к этой задаче.

Думаю никак, ТГ ни передает общее количество файлов в группе, ни их список. Единственное что можно учесть, так это то что уведомление приходит когда все файлы загружены на сервера. Также можно попробовать включить в название файла его индекс и общее количество (1_из_10), к примеру, и посмотреть если дойдёт до получателя.

Пока складывается впечатление, что Telegram Bot API является урезанной версией API, которым пользуется клиент/приложение телеги, в т.ч. и в части работы с сообщениями. В отсутствии этих важных методов придётся записывать содержимое всех сообщений в БД, и уже там извлекать/мёрджить всю цепочку. Конечно, это не очень удобно и изящно, но альтернативы телега нам не даёт. Возможно, это добавят в bot API позже.

Ещё из наблюдений - первым из такой "пачки" всегда прилетает update, содержащий текстовое описание - поле Caption (вместо поля Text) вместе со ссылкой на первое фото/медиа из альбома. А во всех остальных update'ах - по одной ссылке на файл. Но об этом нигде в справке на API не говориться, а значит, либо об этом забыли упомянуть, либо такая последовательность не гарантирована протоколом.
